# ASP .netcore WebAPI only processing local requests

Tags: linux, nginx, asp.net-core-webapi, raspberry-pi4

Hi I am returning 200 on local / requests from the same IP but the below error when I hotspot my mobile phone to change IP and make the request

> HTTPConnectionPool(host={myIPAddress}, port=80): Max retries exceeded
> ..... Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A
> connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
> respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
> because connected host has failed to respond'

**program.cs file**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000/")
        .UseKestrel(serverOptions =>
        {
            //Set properties and call methods on serverOptions
            serverOptions.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
            serverOptions.Limits.MaxConcurrentConnections = 100;
            serverOptions.Limits.MaxConcurrentUpgradedConnections = 100;
            serverOptions.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 10 * 1024;
            serverOptions.Limits.RequestHeadersTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        });
}
```

**NGINX - sites-available/default**

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name   HFTest;

location / {
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000; **#edited as per comments**
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

**Port Status - sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN**

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      635/nginx: master p
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      628/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2048/API/HFTest
```

Any ideas on what to troubleshoot next?

Thankyou

**EDIT:**

**Request - in python**

```
scopes = 'openid'
url='http://{IPAddress}:80/connect/token'

session = OAuth2Session(clientID,clientSecret, scope=scopes)
token = session.fetch_access_token(url,verify=False)

endpoint = "http://{IPAddress}/{endpoint}"

headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer %s" % token['access_token'],"Accept": "text/xml"}

session = requests.Session()

response = session.request("GET",endpoint,headers=headers,verify = False)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: Hello, Could you please provide us with the request you are performing ?
I mean the URI you are using for both local and external requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upstream service ip in your nginx configuration needs to be an actual ip address. You can try the localhost ip as follows

```
…
location / {
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000;
…
```

Comment: I believe this is it! As per the documentation `http://localhost:5000` would work too. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

Comment: @chue x thanks for some insight, I set it to that localhost configuration didn't work
I changed UseUrls aswell didn't work.
I changed both to {IPAddress}:5000; didn't work

Comment: @Paulo I tried both versions and no luck :(

Comment: I would suggest you bypass nginx for now to have less moving pieces. Could you please give us the request you are making ?

Comment: Thanks @Paulo I have updated the original post with request

The remote IP request gets stuck on 
token = session.fetch_access_token(url,verify=False)

Comment: I also removed openiddict layer and still showing winerror 10060

Comment: @HJB did you try 127.0.0.1? localhost sometimes resolves to the ipv6 address ::1.  From your code it looks like your .net service is not ipv6.  You said you tried the actual IP address, but depending on what the address is, your firewall may not allow it.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help troubleshooting this, port forwarding wasn't setup correctly